# Installing R packages

Tags: r

When I have tried to install some R packages such as Rgraphviz, I get the following error:

```
install.packages("Rgraphviz_2.12.0.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
* installing *source* package 'Rgraphviz' ...

**********************************************
WARNING: this package has a configure script
     It probably needs manual configuration
**********************************************


** libs
gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -        
I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"  -                                
Ilibwin/i386/include/graphviz -DHAVE_STDBOOL_H=1 -DHAVE_BOOL=1 - 
DGRAPHVIZ_MAJOR=2 -DGRAPHVIZ_MINOR=28 -DGRAPHVIZ_STATIC   -O3 -Wall  -
std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c LL_funcs.c -o LL_funcs.o
gcc: unrecognized option `-std=gnu99'
d:\RCompile\CRANpkg\extralibs64\local\include\.: Permission denied
make.exe: *** [LL_funcs.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-    
31~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk"  
SHLIB="Rgraphviz.dll" OBJECTS="LL_funcs.o Rgraphviz.o RgraphvizInit.o   
agopen.o agread.o agwrite.o bezier.o buildEdgeList.o buildNodeList.o    
doLayout.o graphvizVersion.o init.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rgraphviz'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/Rgraphviz'
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l     
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\library" "Rgraphviz_2.12.0.tar.gz"' had status 1 
 2: In install.packages("Rgraphviz_2.12.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type =    
 "source") :
 installation of package ‘Rgraphviz_2.12.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I am mostly appreciate any comment.

Comment: Have you tried installing directly from bioconductor, using the [instructions](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Rgraphviz.html) on the page?

Comment: Is it not possible to go into your R console an just type "install.packages("Rgraphviz")"; choose a CRAN and it installs? This works for me.

Comment: I could install it successfuly from Bioconductor!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is take care of the

```
d:\RCompile\CRANpkg\extralibs64\local\include\.: Permission denied
```

error. Check file permissions on that directory; does it belong to Administrator? Make sure you have read access to it.